# How to reference a package full of images

Tags: java

I am making a game using the java swig GUI components and I have a package I have created that stores all of the images I need. For some reason though, the program is not recognizing that image package but will recognize the package with all the game code in it. Any ideas why this might happen. The images package is full of jpg files and I am trying to access them from my GUI package.

EDIT: My whole goal is to change a picture while referencing that picture from another package. My understanding is that a package is just like another folder in that java program that it can access.

Comment: Have you tried get `resourceAsStream`? You need to show some relevant part of the code.

Comment: no I have not. I will let you know if that is a good solution.

Comment: How would you use getResourceAsStream?

Comment: Post your code, tell us what you expect it to do, and what it does instead. Precisely.

Comment: package applies to java classes, not project resources (like images).  see the peeskillet answer for a way to access your images.

Answer (score 0):

Example file Structure:

```
ProjectRoot
          src
              images
                   you image files here
```

Code to retreive

```
// try/catch IOException
URL url = getClass().getResource("/images/someImage.png");
Image image = ImageIO.read(url);
```

The above should work

Comment: Im pretty sure you gotta convert the images folder (or whatever folder contains the images) to a src folder before calling "getResource", dont you? Correct me if Im wrong

Comment: @VinceEmigh Huh?? I Don't even know what that means _"convert the images folder to a src folder"_ All packages i.e. `images` if in the `src` gets built into the class path automatically (at least if using an IDE) and the call to `getResource()` reads from the class path

Comment: Looked into it, and you would be required to change it to a source folder if it didnt already fall under one (src). So yeah, in this case, its not needed. But it something you should at least know about. Coverting a regular system folder into a source folder is actually a thing, dont ya know..

Comment: @VinceEmigh Who said anything about a system folder? Look at my file structure. The OP clearly states the images is a package

Comment: "My understanding is that a package is just like another folder in that java program that it can access" This is a very broad statement, as well as your answer, containing no explination. The OP never specified the directory of where his images were, and as I said, your answer teaches him nothing (it actually encourages c&p). I asked about something relevant, no need to be a peeskillet, buddy..

Comment: @VinceEmigh so now we're just coming up with excuses to argue. I see. Later dude, got no time for people like you.

Comment: Im not, Im trying to help to the community to prevent people from coming back, answering the same questions. I only brough up the source folder because it does play a part, or it wouldnt even exist. When answering, give an explination of why it works. Next time, try to be less hostile when someome asks for reassurance. At first, it was a question I had (which is why I stated "correct me if im wrong". Acting like you have no idea what a source folder is rather rude. Its either youve heard of it or you havent. If you havent, you should just say so, instead of being so volatile..